# Retrieve last events from an Apache Camel route

Tags: events, apache-camel

When a Camel route starts, the status of the route changes. However it happens that the route starts correctly, but there are log warning/errors during start/runtime (for example incorrect password when starting a FTP component).

These events are logged into the console/log file. I want to get these events programmatically (outside the Camel DSL). For example getEvents(routeID, typeEvent, xNumberOfEvents){}.

Are these events cached somewhere by Camel? Can I retrieve the events by something like the ManagedRouteMBean? Or should I write my own caching mechanism using the event notifier (similar to the RiderEventNotifier example) or some kind of errorhandler?

For example to following message is written to the log:

```
2018-10-11 22:15:24.719  WARN 3820 --- [ XNIO-2 task-12] 
o.a.c.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer  : Error auto creating directory:  
due File operation failed: 530 This server does not allow plain FTP. You have 
to use FTP over TLS.
. Code: 530. This exception is ignored.

org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File 
operation failed: 530 This server does not allow plain FTP. You have to use
FTP over TLS.
. Code: 530
```

The issue with the above is that the route start up normal. So

```
ManagedRouteMBean route = context.getManagedRoute(id, ManagedRouteMBean.class);

RouteError lastError = route.getLastError();
```

returns no error.

Also this seems not errors in the exchange, so the errorhandler or event notifiers don't intercept these messages.

I would like to intercept (and cache) such messages by routeid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to handle these kinds of warnings/errors by the normal errorhandler by use of a so-call bridgeErrorHandler. See: http://camel.apache.org/why-does-my-file-consumer-not-pick-up-the-file-and-how-do-i-let-the-file-consumer-use-the-camel-error-handler.html